# My discord.py bot running on heroku keeps stopping

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

I have a very basic discord.py bot hosted on heroku. Its only function is to send a message from a list of possible messages every 24 hours. It always sends the first message and then stops. I can't find any errors in the code, and when I lower the timings and test it both running on my computer and running in heroku, it works fine.

It's all on one python file, with a few required files for heroku and the two text documents for messages.

Here is the main script:

```
import discord
import time
import random as rng

clnt = discord.Client()
ch = 0 #channel id
cnt = 0 #amount of minutes on timer
lp = True #i think this is just a leftover variable from another version, i can't find anywhere i used it


@clnt.event
async def on_ready():
    print('ready')


async def ph(): #function to send message
    global ch
    global lp

    qts = open('quotes.txt') #get messages
    qtz = qts.read().splitlines() #put messages in a list
    qts.close() #close file
    
    #if message file is empty, get the list from a backup file and put them into the first file, reseting the messages
    if not qtz:  
        qts2 = open('quoteslog.txt') 
        qtz2 = qts2.read().splitlines()
        qts2.close()

        with open('quotes.txt', 'w') as f:
            for i in qtz2:
                f.write("%s\n" % i)
            f.close()

        qts = open('quotes.txt')
        qtz = qts.read().splitlines()
        qts.close()

    #get random message from list
    x = rng.randint(1, len(qtz))
    x2 = x - 1
    y = qtz[x2]
    qtz.pop(x2)

    open('quotes.txt', 'w').close() #clear the list

    #rewrite the same file without the message sent
    with open('quotes.txt', 'w') as f:
        for i in qtz:
            f.write("%s\n" % i)
        f.close()
    
    #used for messages with new lines
    if y == 'ph1':
        await ch.send("this is for one of the messages, it has new lines so it can't be re-inserted into a txt file")
        await timer()

    elif y == 'ph2':
        await ch.send('same here')
        await timer()

    else:
        #send message to channel and restart the timer
        await ch.send(y)
        await timer()


@clnt.event
async def on_message(m):
    if m.author == clnt.user:
        return

    global ch

    if m.content.startswith('send here'):
        ch = clnt.get_channel(m.channel.id)
        await m.channel.send('ok')

    elif m.content.startswith('start'):
        await timer()


async def timer():  #loops every 60 seconds, 1440 times, or 24hrs
    global lp
    while lp:
        global cnt
        time.sleep(60)
        cnt += 1
        if cnt == 1440:
            cnt = 0 #reset timer and send message
            await ph() 


clnt.run('the discord bot id')
```

Yes, I know the code is probably garbage formatting-wise, but as far as I can tell it should be working and it isn't. I'm not even sure if it's a code error, could also be a heroku problem, but I have no idea.

If anyone has anything that could possibly help that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do your heroku logs say?

Comment: Also you are looping in timer. But then timer calls ph. Which call timers. So even if this code was working it would be very broken.

Comment: will check logs and update in the morning. as for the ph() calling timer(), yea I'm stupid lol. I'm p sure I actually didn't have that earlier then for some reason saw I didn't have it and thought I needed it, probably forgot timer was a loop or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you use the `Bot` and `Cog` classes, it will be much more efficient, they are provided in discord.py, and **have decorators to define a looping function**. They are in the `discord.ext.commands` part of the module. You can do:

```py
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
```

I just answered on another post with an example of a cog and a looping function, you'll find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63298402/14061203). Here is the same structure adapted to your case:

```py
# LoopCog.py
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import random

class LoopCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.test_loop.change_interval(minutes = self.bot.cnt)

    @commands.Cog.listener("on_ready")
    async def on_ready(self):
        self.test_loop.start()

    @tasks.loop(hours=24)
    async def test_loop(self):
        # insert your ph function contents here
        # access the channel id via self.bot.ch

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(LoopCog(bot))
```

```py
# main.py
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")
bot.ch = 0 
bot.cnt = 0
bot.load_extension("LoopCog")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("ready")

bot.run(token, reconnect = True)
```

I suggest you go watch some tutorials. Using the `Client` class for a `Bot` is not the right way to go, you will have to program everything that is already in `Bot` if you keep going with `Client`.

You'll find the API documentation [here](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for [Bot](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#bot), [Cog](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#cogs), and [tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html#api-reference)

Concerning *heroku*, **it will unfortunately restart your bot every 24h**, unless you go for a paying professional offer which includes 24/7 runtime. It will also put your program in sleep mode if it doesn't get any request within 30 min.

Comment: Would having a loop that runs every minute or so, stop the bot from sleeping?

Comment: @AryanGarg since the bot is put to sleep if it doesn't receive external request, an inner loop wouldn't change a thing. You might however create another bot which sends requests periodically to the one you try to keep awake, but that would need some testing to find a good way to do so.